# Does every spring-mvc controller(resp handlerMapping) has the AlwaysUseFullPath property?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Lets consider i have this snippet in my context-config:

```
<bean id="handlerMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping">
      <property name="alwaysUseFullPath" value="false"/>
</bean>
```

This means that when the the dispatcher will want to contact the **handlerMapping**, it will truncate the alias. so for example this alias **/my/request** will become **/request** and the **handlerMapping** will be therefore contacted with the **/request** alias.

Referring to this http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.6/reference/mvc.html
i'm seeing that the **alwaysUseFullPath** property is configurable for **SimpleUrlHandlerMapping** and **BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping**.

I would like to know (if possible by a ref link) whether all spring-mvc **handlerMapping** (resp  **controller**) got the **alwaysUseFullPath** property or not.

Thanks

Comment: Where did you see this property?

Comment: follow this http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.6/reference/mvc.html   section 13.4

Comment: That's a very old version of Spring. The document you posted states _They both extend the `AbstractHandlerMapping` and share the following properties_ [`alwaysUseFullPath`]. So any implementation of `HandlerMapping` that extends `AbstractHandlerMapping` will have that property.

Comment: and what about controllers?

Comment: It's not a property of controllers, it's a property of `AbstractHandlerMapping`.

Comment: Do you know that the AbstractUrlViewController (see this ref https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/AbstractUrlViewController.html) which is the Abstract base class for Controllers that return a view name based on the request URL got a setter method for that property? I do think that all the controllers extending the AbstractUrlViewController will got that property!

Comment: Ah, you're still sticking to old patterns. I thought you meant `@Controller` annotated types.